# FOR cycle in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a really basic batch file, but I am stuck on this problem. I have written:

> for %n in (1 1 10) do pause

For what I understand, this should open a terminal window and pause 10 times. The problem is that when I run the batch, the terminal window only flashes open and doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the terminal window "flashes", it's likely displaying an error message that you just don't have time to read.  Add a `pause` at the end of your batch file to force it to wait until you hit Enter; or better yet, open a command window yourself and run the batch file from there so it doesn't have to open a new window each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is the single `%`.  That's the right syntax for running this directly at the command line, but in a batch file you need to use `%%`.  See `help for` for details.

Additionally, the code you wrote will only call `pause` three times:  once for the `1`, once for the second `1`, and once for the `10`.  If you want to loop from 1 to 10 stepping by 1, you need to use `/l`:

```
for /l %%n in (1 1 10) do pause
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way, for the loop you forgot an /l after the for ;) I don't think you actually even need the commas if you put it...

Comment: You're right, I forgot the `/l`, and the commas are unnecessary!  I'd never even tried it without the commas, as the docs indicate to separate by commas.  Strange but true!  :-)  I've updated my answer.  Please mark it as Accepted if it correctly answers your question.

Comment: You can use every default delimiter: `;= ,`